# If "x" is in column A and "y" is in column B, I want column C to be 5. I have a list of about 190 values. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I have a list of 190 column c values that correspond to specific column a and column b values. I created a huge if statement, but excel says it's too large and I keep messing up parentheses. What is a more efficient way to solve this problem? For example, if column A is "United" and column B is "Brain", I want column C to be 150. All for the first value. Thank you.

Comment: I have a separate excel sheet with the column a values and column b values that correspond to the 190 column c values

Comment: I'm not an excel user, but sounds like you need something like VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP. Here's link to docs: http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in column A and B. Use concatenate in column C:

```
Concatenate(A1, B1)
```

Then in your sheet with the values, insert a column between the values column and the two criteria columns. Use concatenate in that column as well (sane formula as above).

Then on the first sheet in column D use the formula:

```
vlookup(C1, Sheet2!C1:D190, 2, false)
```

This is assuming your second sheet is sheet 2 yadda yadda.

Let me know if you run into an issue!